# Behavour of the rpois function

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand a proposed solution for a University test.
Let me assume that we have created a random variable with

```
set.seed(123)
R <- 5
X <- rexp(R, 2)
```

So the content of `X` is

```
0.42172863 0.28830514 0.66452743 0.01578868 0.02810549
```

In the solutions of the problem I find

```
Y <- rpois(R, exp(X / 4))
```

where the content of `exp(X / 4)` is

```
1.111191 1.074737 1.180729 1.003955 1.007051
```

where, contrary to my expectations the second argument is an array instead of being a scalar.

If I calculate

```
print(rpois(R, 1.111191))
print(rpois(R, 1.074737))
print(rpois(R, 1.180729))
print(rpois(R, 1.003955))
print(rpois(R, 1.007051))
```

I get

```
2 1 1 3 1
1 1 0 2 0
0 1 3 3 2
1 4 1 1 1
1 0 0 3 2
```

while for `rpois(R, exp(X / 4))` I get

```
1 2 0 1 2
```

How are the two results related?

It's a behaviour I can't find explained anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

R makes its functions **vectorized** wherever it's reasonable to do so.

In particular, in the function call `rpois(R, lambda)`, `R` specifies the number of samples to take, and `lambda` is the vector of means, **which is recycled to match `R`**. In other words, if `lambda` is a single value then the same mean will be used for each Poisson draw; if it is a vector of length `R`, then each element of the vector will be used for the corresponding Poisson draw.

So the equivalent of `Y <- rpois(R, exp(X / 4))` would be

```r
Y <- c(
   rpois(1, exp(X[1]/4),
   rpois(1, exp(X[2]/4),
   rpois(1, exp(X[3]/4),
   ...
)
```

We could also do this with a `for` loop:

```r
Y <- numeric(R)  ## allocate a length-R numeric vector
for (i in seq(R)) {
  Y[i] <- rpois(1, exp(X[i]/4))
}
```

Using the vectorized version whenever it's available is best practice; it's faster and requires less code (therefore easier to understand).